# Python Executing Json with backslash

Tags: python, json, parsing, selenium, backslash

I have json string, which i need to execute in selenium script using python, but i think `/"` making it difficult to parse

```
var t = {
      "s": {
        "2MqcJqtmNYDZlcbDZY3yjA==": "[{\"id\":\"global_mute\",\"expiration\":0}]",
        "BrowserId": "\"TAMGVxD/wr9fL47xJZAciw==\"",
        "SecretBundle": "{\"key\":\"2Eiw3rJZI9oErblie5mx+xXPjd+tj6t0hqQHC+EQ8Bc=\",\"encKey\":\"aGLPEm0dyq6W/gHN5cVONhdOR6lv2CGm4v4GLJ7LyoM=\",\"macKey\":\"2Eiw3rJZI9oErblie5mx+xXPjd+tj6t0hqQHC+EQ8Bc=\"}",
        "Token1": "\"OG7aZ02ndonc1DGnfJ3bswG3na3Wr5OB7bwdgiwdd4Y=\"",
        "Token2": "\"1@Sf53vRMCbVuLW0Q1diEg95TVBWRMDOjG7mqI8XIfOjr+hMiTwyqjKM72NKgxZJBGtfkETDmqfCgVLQ==\"",
        "Xz+yNzfxx8EbdaUFWVxmjg==": "false",
        "debugCursor": "191",
        "ghI8QhVRLDvFWJDpV7Cx5g==": "false",
        "logout-token": "\"1@MZ9F8QbLN9iGKNeZGbCJdzKwPHq7L5sJrpO6RtiG35rdu5TVLu/+z3gGNmbYG59h1Grzfwcnz44uLVencqRdP044ZpWuT02+ltcEM+9aCURZQkBG+oRyeWNAHcInXMWCpWysPF5d/ISLnbfeV1NVoA==\"",
        "remember-me": "true",
        "storage_test": "storage_test"
      },
      "c": ""
    }
```

i used `r'var t = whole json string'`, but its not working.
Do i need to covert backslash first ?

Comment: that is not a json string... it's a dictionary already... get rid of the `var` and you have a valid python expression.